# Embarrassingly easy stats question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have a large set of values (1000) that are each a measure of accuracy for a large set of corresponding models that were generated using random data. I want to compare a single measure of accuracy, for a single model not generated from random data, to these accuracy measures for the random models so that I can show that the non-random one is significantly better than we'd expect from random data.

That is: I have a single accuracy value for my model-not-generated-from-random-data (ROC AUC), as well as a single accuracy value (same) for each of my 1000 models-generated-from-random-data.

What test statistics do I need? I know I could run my model using the non-random data a number of times and compare the means of the measures of accuracy between the two, but running the model takes some time, and I'd prefer not to have to do that. I know there has to be a way to reject the hypothesis that my non-random measure came from the random set of data...

Comment: I find the situation slightly unclear. Do you have only a single accuracy value for your model-not-generated-from-random-data, or do you have one for each random set of data, or something else? Could you clarify your experiment and what data you have?

Comment: Yes, a single accuracy value for my model-not-generated-from-random-data (ROC AUC), as well as a single accuracy value (same) for each of my 1000 models-generated-from-random-data.

Comment: Please also insert any clarification you give into your question.

Comment: [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_permutation_test_for_classification.html#example-feature-selection-plot-permutation-test-for-classification-py) might help you.

Comment: ssdecontrol - That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for - is there a place where this is written in a more understandable fashion? The English is a little unclear, and it looks like I'll have to decipher the code. As it is it almost makes sense...